# Citations not linking to bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, cite-package, ieeeconf

In my thesis, I use the url and hyperref packages (they were included as part of a thesis template) to get links from where a work is cited to where that citation is in the bibliography (and it works great). I am trying to do the same thing in a paper I'm writing, however when I build that paper, the links to figures and tables work, but links to the references do not. A MWE is:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\pdfoptionpdfminorversion 6

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}         % allows for subfigures
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\let\Algorithm\algorithm
\renewcommand\algorithm[1][]{\Algorithm[#1]\setstretch{1.15}}

\lefthyphenmin4
\righthyphenmin4

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{placeins}

% *** PDF, URL AND HYPERLINK PACKAGES ***

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[pdftex,backref,pagebackref,plainpages=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    breaklinks   = false, % Allow link text to break across lines (default=false).
    colorlinks   = false, % Color the text of links (true) or put color frames over
    linkbordercolor  = {1 1 1}, % The color of the box around normal links (white so they won't show up)
    citebordercolor  = {1 1 1}, % The color of the box around citations (white so they won't show up)
                          % the links (false).
    pdfstartview = {FitV}, % Set the startup page view. Possible options are:
                           % FitH: Fit whole width of page
                           % FitV: Fit whole height of page
                           % FitB: Fit whole ?Bounding Box? page
                           % FitBH: Fit whole width of ?Bounding Box? of page
                           % FitBV: Fit whole height of ?Bounding Box? of page
    bookmarksnumbered  = true, % Put section numbers in bookmarks (default=false)
    bookmarksopen      = true, % Open up the bookmark trees (default=false).
    bookmarksopenlevel = 0, % Level to which bookmarks are open (default=\maxdimen).
    bookmarkstype      = toc, % Specify which toc file to mimic (default=toc).
    pdfpagemode        = {UseOutlines}, %  Specify how document starts when opened ({None}).
                                        % Possible options are:,
                                        % None: Neither bookmarks nor thumbnails are visible.
                                        % UseOutlines: Bookmarks are visible.
                                        % UseThumbs: Thumbnails are visible.
                                        % FullScreen: Full-screen mode
    pdftitle    = {My Title},
    pdfauthor   = {Authors},
    pdfcreator  = {PDF Creator},
    pdfsubject  = {PDF Subject},
    pdfkeywords = {PDF Keywords},
    pdfborder       =   {0 0 0},}

\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500

\begin{document}
\title{\LARGE \bf My Title}

\author{Me%
%
\thanks{Me \href{mailto:me@gmail.com}{\tt\footnotesize me@gmail.com}}}  %% End the author section

% make the title area
\maketitle

\abstract
My abstract
\endabstract

Blah blah list of citations now \cite{Stone2001_2} and \cite{Green2005}.

\clearpage

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

This requires the ieeeconf.cls file.  The refs.bib file contains (among other references):

```
@inproceedings{Green2005,
address = {Monterey, CA},
author = {Green, WE and Oh, PY},
booktitle = {Proceedings, 2005 IEEE/ASME International Conference on Advanced Intelligent Mechatronics.},
doi = {10.1109/AIM.2005.1511063},
isbn = {0-7803-9047-4},
keywords = {Aerial Robots,Fixed wing UAV,Hover,Unmanned Aerial Vehicles},
pages = {693--698},
publisher = {IEEE},
title = {{A MAV That Flies Like an Airplane and Hovers Like a Helicopter}},
url = {http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=1511063},
year = {2005}
}
@conference{Stone2001_2,
address = {Canberra},
author = {Stone, Roland Hugh and Clarke, G},
booktitle = {Australian International Aerospace Congress},
month = mar,
title = {{Optimization of Transition Maneuvers for a Tailsitter Unmanned Air Vehicle}},
year = {2001}
}
```

Any idea on what I'm missing? I am on Windows 7 and use TeXstudio.

edit: I've done a little additional troubleshooting and it seems if for the document class I replace ieeeconf with report, then all works as it should. Is there a reason ieeeconf is preventing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns that the ieeeconf.cls file contains this comment:

```
% 11/2002 V1.6b (MDS) changes:
%
% 1) Fixed problem with figure captions when using hyperref. Thanks to 
%    Leandro Barajas and Michael Bassetti for reporting this bug.
%
% 2) Provide a fake nabib command \NAT@parse so that hyperref will not
%    interfere with the operation of cite.sty. However, as a result citation
%    numbers will not be hyperlinked. Also, natbib will not be able to work
%    with IEEEtran. However, this is perhaps the best solution until cite.sty
%    and hyperref.sty are able to co-exist with each other.
%    It easy enough to override the fake command via:
%    \makeatletter
%    \let\NAT@parse\undefined
%    \makeatother
```

Accordingly, I added the following before loading the url and hyperref packages:

```
\makeatletter
\let\NAT@parse\undefined
\makeatother
```

and all works as it should.  While trying to figure this out, I have read (unfortunately I can't find the source) that cite and hyperref are now compatible with each other. I used them together in my thesis just fine and didn't have any issues.

Comment: With current MiKTeX (and all packages up to date), the problem still persists. Hyperref 6.86b, cite.sty not installed at all. The above mentioned 3 lines of code fix it, though.